# custom template form fields django

Tags: django, templates, django-forms

i tried to use my own template style instead of default django form style , it work fine for creating post but doesnt work for update my formsets (inlineformset) , it also work if i use default django form style

this my views.py

```
class TitleQuestionAnswer(LoginRequiredMixin,UserPassesTestMixin,UpdateView):
    model = Title
    form_class = TitleForm
    template_name = 'template/update_title_question.html'

    def get_context_data(self,*args,**kwargs):
        context = super(TitleQuestionAnswer,self).get_context_data(*args,**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
           context['questions'] = QA_InlineFormset(self.request.POST,instance=self.object)
        else:
           context['questions'] = QA_InlineFormset(instance=self.object)
        return context


    def form_valid(self,form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        context = context['questions']
        self.object = form.save()
        if context.is_valid() and context.cleaned_data !={}:

           response = super().form_valid(form)
           context.instance = self.object
           context.save()
           return response
        print('errors : ',context.errors, 'data : ',context.cleaned_data)#updated
        return super().form_invalid(form)
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('q-answer:post',kwargs={'pk':self.object.pk})
```

and this is my template

```html
<form method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
        <div class="col-6 inp text-center">
                {{form.name | add_class:'col-12 text-center'}}
                {% if form.name.errors %}
                <div class="error col-3 mx-auto">{{form.name.errors}}</div>
                {% endif %}

        </div>
        </div>
        <!-- order -->
        <div class="col-12 p-0 border-top border-light ">

            <table class="customeTable col-12 table-responsive-sm info text-center table1 mx-auto mb-2  ">
        <tbody class="tbody tb1 " id="form_set">
            {{questions.management_form}}
            {% for form in questions.forms %}
            {{form.errors}} <!--updated-->
            {{questions.errors}}
            {{questions.non_form_errors}}
            {{form.id}}
            <tr class="p-0 col-12">
                
                <td class="">
                    <div class="col-12 p-0 mt-3 inp">
                        {{form.field_a | add_class:'col-12'}}
        
                    </div>
                </td>
        
                <td class="">
                    <div class="col-12 p-0 mt-3 inp">
                        {{form.field_b | add_class:'col-12'}}
        
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </form>
```

but if i change it to only `{{questions.management_form}} {% for form in questions.forms %} {{form}}{% 
endfor %}`

this style works fone for my `CreateView` !
it will work fine !? is there something i missed ? or should i add or remove something in my code ?
i appreciate your helps ..

Comment: Your custom template doesn't show any errors, so you can't tell what the problem is. I would try adding `{{ questions.errors }}`, `{{questions.non_form_errors }}` and `{{ form.errors }}` to the template. You can also try adding printing/logging in the view to try to find out the errors there.

Comment: still my form.cleaned_data is an empty list !

Comment: there is no error to show in the template

Comment: only the parent form will be updated

Comment: You haven't shown where you added that debugging code to the view/templates.

Comment: i updated the post with debugging code for both views/template

Comment: isnt there a solution please ?

Comment: You have `print('errors : ', ...)` inside the `is_valid()` - but when the formset is valid, there won't be any errors. You want to check the errors when the formset isn't valid.

Comment: i put it inside invalid() nothing will happen , the form will be saved without any changes , but Parent forms will be changed

Comment: Put it after the `if is_valid()` check, but keep it in the same method. As I said earlier, `UpdateView` isn't meant to handle formsets, so it makes getting this stuff correct tricky. `context` isn't a good name for the variable - it's a formset, not the context dict.

Comment: i've changed the name in my project , and i put it right there , and updated the post,and cleaned_data still an empty list []

Comment: `print('errors : ',` doesn't show any errors after moving it? You should try printing the non form errors as well.

Comment: Maybe you are missing a form field when you loop through the formset. You could try [looping over the fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/#looping-over-hidden-and-visible-fields) to make sure you aren't missing any.

Comment: Please show `QA_InlineFormset` and its model.

Comment: doesnt show any errors , i will update the post

Comment: this is not my original project , i will show the original

Comment: i appreciate your helps ..

Comment: {{ form.errors }} returns >  id This field is required.

Comment: thanks alot i solved

Comment: i much appreciate you , love you buddy